# Lambda function and 0

Tags: python

I want to make a function that changes each elements in list with lambda function.

```
a = [1,5,2,4]

def func1(list,func2):
    for x in range(len(list)):
        list[x] = func2(list[x])

func1(a,lambda x: x>3 and 10 or x)
print a
```

The result is [1,10,2,10]

This is OK. But I change '10' to '0'

```
func1(a,lambda x: x>3 and 0 or x)
```

The result is [1,5,2,4]

Why doesn't the result be [1,0,2,0]?

I'm sorry that I'm poor at English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that [`0` is being evaluated as `False`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) which means that using [the `and`-`or` trick](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html#d0e9975) as a conditional expression is failing.

[Python 2.5 introduced "proper" conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions) of the form:

```
x = true_value if condition else false_value
```

So you can replace:

```
lambda x: x>3 and 0 or x
```

with:

```
lambda x: 0 if x > 3 else x
```

Also, you could use [the `map` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) to replace `func1` if you're not bothered about updating the list in place:

```
a = map(lambda x: 0 if x > 3 else x,a)
print a
```

If you do want to modify the list in place you can use [the `enumerate` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to simplify your code a little:

```
def func1(list,func2):
    for i,x in enumerate(list):
        list[i] = func2(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

bool(0) -> False

bool(10) -> True

Answer (score 1):

```
a and b or c
```

is equivalent (nearly, since your case proves it is not) to

```
b if a else c
```

So:

```
a = [1,5,2,4]

def func1(li,func2):
    for x,el in enumerate(li):
        li[x] = func2(el)

func1(a,lambda x: 0 if x>3 else x)
print a
```

Remark:

- name **list** for a user's object is not good
- use of **iterate()**

By the way, did you notice that you are changing in a function the value of an object external to the function ?

```
u = 102

def f(x):
    x = 90

print "u==",u
```

result

```
u== 102
```

In your code, **a** is changed because it is a mutable object

In common case, a function has a return. Yours has not, because you change a mutable object.

Answer (score 0):

`x>3 and 0 or x` always returns `x` because `0` is `False`.

Replace it with:

```
(x > 3 and [0] or [x])[0]
```

to get:

```
func1(a,lambda x: (x>3 and [0] or [x])[0])
```

Result:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0]
```

How it works:

1. The real return value is put into a single element list.
   Any non-empty list is `True`, so the `and` `or` works.
2. Then use `[0]` to get the value back out.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn it around:

```
func1(a,lambda x: x<=3 and x or 0)
```

(untested)